# Meaning of purple blinking on Sony Ericsson Play (R800)?

Tags: system-error, sony-ericsson-xperia-play

The phone went off and I cannot turn it on. I tried pulling battery out, but it did not help. Cannot also connect it to SEUS since it does not detect a mobile connected.

Now, when I connect a mobile on USB charger and press the power button, the screen quickly blinks for less than 1s and then then **purple light keeps blinking (flashing)**.

The purple light is coming from the **LED on the power button**. When I connect the charger the screen first turn to green, I think. And when I try to turn the mobile on, the screen turns to purple blinking light.

what is the meaning of the purple light? I cannot find the meaning on the Internet.

Comment: Where is the purple light coming from? The screen, or the notification led/light?

Comment: @geffchang Just edited the question explaining the location of the light.